# Could not get type signature for class package..Line

Tags: java, gwt, objectify

The example is realized using GWT and Objectify version 5.0.3.
The case is produced when i trying save instances of Document.
I obtain the error:

Could not get type signature for class Line

Have you one idea of it?

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")

@Entity
public class GenericEntity implements Serializable {

     @Id  protected Long id;

}



@SuppressWarnings("serial")

@Entity

public class Document extends GenericEntity implements Serializable {

     @Index  private String name;

     @Serialize  private List<Session> sessions = new ArrayList<Session>();

}



@SuppressWarnings("serial")

@Entity

public class Session extends GenericEntity implements Serializable {

     private Date date;

     @Serialize  private Vector<Line> transectsH = new Vector<Line>();

     @Serialize  private HashMap<Point, Line> mapperHorizontalLines = newHashMap<Point, Line>();

}



@SuppressWarnings("serial")

@Entity

public class Point extends GenericEntity implements Serializable {

     private double x;

     private double y;

}



@SuppressWarnings("serial")

@Entity

public class Line extends GenericEntity implements Serializable {

     private Point coordinate;

     private Image image;

     private Object data;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the exception from GWT when you try to serialize something. Probably because GWT-RPC cannot serialize something declared of type `Object`.

Answer (score 0):

In objectify you can define a polymorphic hierarchy of related entity classes as I have done for you below. Give the code below and let us know how you get on; caveat: the code has not been tested - all done in a hurry I'm afraid!

Remember that if a Super Class of a Class already implements Serializable interface in Java then its already Serializable in Java - no need for subclasses to implement Serializable

Please not that you will have to explicitly register all subclasses (the ones annotated with @Subclass), otherwise you will get an error!

I would encourage to read the section in objectify documentation that covers polymorphism [Objectify Entities Polymorphism](https://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/wiki/Entities#Polymorphism)

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Entity
public class GenericEntity implements Serializable {

     @Id  protected Long id;
}


@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Subclass
public class Document extends GenericEntity {

     @Index  private String name;

     @Serialize  private List<Session> sessions = new ArrayList<Session>();
}


@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Subclass
public class Session extends GenericEntity {

     private Date date;

     @Serialize  private Vector<Line> transectsH = new Vector<Line>();

     @Serialize  private HashMap<Point, Line> mapperHorizontalLines = newHashMap<Point, Line>();
}


@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Subclass
public class Point extends GenericEntity {

     private double x;

     private double y;
}


@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Subclass

public class Line extends GenericEntity {

     private Point coordinate;

     private Image image;

     private Object data;
}
```